# How to be sure that all views got created

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-view

I'm working with `AsyncTask` and in one of the background threads I've created, I have to know the size of a given `View`. 
But sometimes this view is yet to be created.
So the question is: at which part of Activity's life cycle I can be sure that all the views are already in place and with the dimensions defined?

PS: My code is inside a `Fragment` and I already tried `onResume()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

custom the view which you want to get size:

```
public class SizeFetchableView extends YourView{

//constructors...

private SizeFetchListener mSizeFetchListener;
public void setSizeFetchListener(SizeFetchListener l){
       mSizeFetchListener = l;
}
public void onLayout(boolean isChanged,int l,int t,int r,int b){
       super.onLayout(l,t,r,b);
       if(mSizeFetchListener!=null){
         mSizeFetchListener.onFetchSize(this,isChanged,getWith(),getHeight());
       }
}

public interface SizeFetchListener{
public void onFetchSize(View view,boolean isChanged，int w,int h);
}

}
```

so,you can use SizeFetchListener to get the view size in the first time,but your thread logic which depend on the size,must waiting the fetch size interface invoke.

```
public class Task extends Thread implements SizeFetchListener{
SizeFetchableView mSizeFetchableView;
   public Task(SizeFetchableView v){
          mSizeFetchableView=v;
          mSizeFetchableView.setSizeFetchListner(this);
   }

   public void onFetchSize(View view,boolean isChanged，int w,int h){
   //and this time ,you can start you thread if not,or continue you logic who waiting the size

   }
}
```

//please forgive my bad english.Thanks